# Is there any way to read excel file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, excel

Are there any modules in nodejs that helps us easy to read excel file easily in arrays i have seen module excel are there any other modules we can use except module excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think use can use this: https://github.com/trevordixon/excel.js

```
var parseXlsx = require('excel');

parseXlsx('Spreadsheet.xlsx', function(err, data) {
  if(err) throw err;
    // data is an array of arrays
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx

```
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx');

var obj = xlsx.parse(__dirname + '/myFile.xlsx'); // parses a file 

var obj = xlsx.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/myFile.xlsx')); // parses a buffer
```